# How to output a 3D tensor from a neural network?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, neural-network

My main input feature is 60x256x256 numpy array that is meant to generate a 60x256x256 binary mask (also in the form of a numpy array). The binary mask functions as a label, but I do not know how to generate a 3D numpy array or tensor output from my neural network. This is my current code:

```
model = tf.keras.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(5, 5), strides=(1, 1),
                 activation='relu',
                 input_shape=(60, 256, 256)))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=(2, 2)))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, (5, 5), activation='relu'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Flatten())
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(1000, activation='relu'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(256, activation='softmax'))

model.compile(
    optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(0.001),
    loss=tf.keras.losses.CosineSimilarity(),
    metrics=[tf.keras.metrics.CosineSimilarity()],
)

model.fit(
    train,
    epochs=6,
    validation_data=ds_valid,
)
```

In short, I want the output of the last layer to match the input layer so that it can work with the CosineSimilarity loss function. Any suggestions other than this CNN-based approach will also be very helpful, as it seems CNNs are mostly used for classification.

Answer (score 1):

At the most basic level you can use `tf.keras.layers.Reshape`. See https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/generative/autoencoder
So your last two layers could be:

```
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(60*256*256))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Reshape(60, 256, 256))
```

However I think what you're looking for is an autoencoder type network and to use`tf.keras.layers.Conv2DTranspose` layers.
The above link is an intro to Autoencoders and should be a good starting point I think.

Not sure about your use case but I think it's very likely you do want to use a convolution based approach because when you flatten the convolution you are forcing your network to forget all the information about the symmetry of the problem (i.e that it is a picture in 2D space). I don't think the fact that your problem is a regression problem affects this.